# jQuery delay in firing function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script in my page that's part of the "DynamicPage" script, and I've added a part to call a function to make my image slider script run. It's in here to resolve a problem I had before. It works, except for a delay of a split second once the page loads. The images below give you an idea of what I mean.

[As the page loads](http://i.imgur.com/uhxVu.png)

[What it should look like/what it looks like after about half a second](http://i.imgur.com/cB6c5.png)

Here's the script

```
$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        sliderInit = true,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("navbar").delegate("a", "click", function() { window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href"); return false; });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent.find("#guts").slideUp(5, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.slideDown(5, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px" }, function() {
                            $('#games').coinslider({ navigation: true, height:325, width: 595, hoverPause: true, delay: 5000});
                        });
                    });
                    $("navbar a").removeClass("current");
                    $("navbar a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
                });
            });
        };
    });
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Comment: not sure if are you trying to add a delay or if you're trying to remove a half second delay.

Comment: Remove, sorry if i didn't make that clear.

Comment: hmm..i wonder if the half second delay is really your issue.  Your issue is that when the page reloads..you see a picture flash along the bottom?  This appears to me like your DOM isn't ready by the time you fire your slide event.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add an overlay to the page. Say, a black/white background that lies on the top of the page hiding everything else. Now, when your function fires, fade this overlay out, and remove it.

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    sliderInit = true,
    $el;
                .
                .
                .

$("#MY_OVERLAY").hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having your slider trigger after the page complete's loading?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You issue is not a javaScript issue, but rather a Html/CSS issue.

In fact if you were to load your webpage without javaScript (ancient i know, but people are still using XP with ancient browsers out there), it would be stuck at ur "page loading example".

My suggestion is to have a hidden css class, which you apply to all redundant additional dynamic element. Things you want hidden without javaScript, or in your case, the additional image frames. That way not only do you prevent the out of place effect you have seen, you make the website backwards compatible. Important especially if your client target audience may not be IT savy.

```
.preLoadHide {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

After which when (and if) javaScript is loaded, do the following since you are using jQuery [before or after applying the image slides effect requires experimentation]

```
jQuery(".preLoadHide").removeClass(".preLoadHide");
```

---

Note that there is also a very strong reason why we induce the delay via

> $(function() { ... your code here... });

In the context of your code: this ensure javaScript is executed after the images are loaded, as the script will crash/fail/do nothing, to nothing, when nothing is loaded. Hence your 0.5 second delay.

[As your page is still loading, in fact most images are loaded progressively in browsers, when they first appear they are actually incomplete of the higher-res details, which we at times just do not realise it, reducing high-res pictures are part of optimization]

Hence with server load times not being something you always have control over, it is best to assume the delay will always be there. Hence work with it =P